# Creating MDR File with python using user input

Tags: python, user-input

Hi can python create mdr files with the open command or is it just files using user input? I'm trying to make it a .mdr file. It works properly if I use the open command on its own.

```
f=open("test.mdr","w")
```

I'm trying to figure out how to set the file as a `.mdr` with this code.

```
ID=input("Lot ID:")
LotID = ID+'301-320';
with open (LotID, "w") as f:
  f.write(Test)
```

I need the file to be a `.mdr` but it comes out as a `File type`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`LotID = ID + '301-320.mdr'`

- just append `.mdr` extension to `LotID`

Answer (score 1):

With your code you are opening the file `ID+'301-320'`.
So if the user inputs `foobar` you would get `foobar301-320` as filename. 
You could add the extension `.mdr` if you want programs to instantly recognize it as an `.mdr`-file:

```
id = input("Lot ID:")
lot_id = id + '301-320.mdr';
with open (lot_id, "w") as f:
    f.write("Test")
```

Also, you should consider renaming your variables as python variables are usually in snake case.